# How do you use 「どうか」 to mean please?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I came across the vocabulary 「どうか（ください）」. Could you please give an example of it's use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9):

You wouldn't use "どうか" standing by itself.  Added to a request (like てください), I think it adds a nuance of a strong request/entirety/petition.

どうか許{ゆる}してください - please forgive me

どうか、息子{むすこ}を  - please (help/save/look after) my son (sentence with verb dropped)

By comparison, どうぞ　can be used in an invitation/offering sort of sense (please have a seat/please help yourself), whereas どうか cannot.